# How to achieve below thing with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jakarta-ee

I want to disable `Save As` button, `View Source` button and `Print Screen Key` and `Print` functionality of a browser using JavaScript/any other way. To protect users from saving, viewing source and taking screenshot of my secure website. It would be great-full if anyone help me in achieving above things.

Comment: if I meet such a website, i'll just close it and never come back. also, I hate captcha (-_-!)

Comment: I will wait for few more answers....

Comment: I'll just grab my phone and take a photo of your site. How will you block that?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot **RELIABLY** do these things, and nor should you ever force a user to.

Comment: @user1510187 What you have likely seen is websites disabling right-click.  There are still methods around that.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can. Disabling right click with javascript is just a matter of:

```
window.onmousedown = function( e ) {
    if ( e.which === 2 || e.which === 3 ) return false;
};
```

You can also disable selection etc, there is a lot you can do.

Now, let me disable javascript. It's three clicks away in any browser.

Oh wait, all your protections are completely useless.

Comment: Ok... I'll make sure to check in every page, whether javascript is disabled or not?? is it a good plan?? so that user won't disable javascript to circumvent to enable "right click"

Comment: How can you check if javascript is disabled, without javascript? (You can, but it's a pain to maintain.) That's a lot of work for nothing. If I want to steal your content, I can still use any network sniffer or whatever. There are lot of ways.